# Meu erro Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\zayonet\start.php on line 99

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, input

Estou com algum problema neste código abaixo.
Tenho um formulário em que o usuário tem duas opções entre escrever simplesmente um texto e publicar ou um texto com imagem. Infelizmente o `$_FILES["file"]` está sendo identificado dando um erro parecido com:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\zayonet\start.php on
>   line 99
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\zayonet\start.php on
>   line 122
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\zayonet\start.php on
>   line 123

Como posso resolver?

HTML:

```html
  
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 publish">
    
<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-date">
           
<textarea name="texto" placeholder="Write anything here"></textarea>
<label for="file-input"><img src="icons/foto1.png" alt="Insert Photo" 
class="maquina-foto"></label>
<input type="submit" name="POSTER" value="Post" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file-input"  style="display:none;" />

</form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```html
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['POSTER'])) { 

 $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];

 if ($error) {
  $texto = $_POST["texto"];
  $date = date("Y-m-d");

  if ($texto == "") {
   echo "You have to write something";
  }else{
   $query_pubs = BD::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO public (`user` , `texto` , `date`) VALUES (:e , :t , :d)");
   $query_pubs->bindParam(":e", $_SESSION['email_user']);
   $query_pubs->bindParam(":t", $texto);
   $query_pubs->bindParam(":d", $date);
   $query_pubs->execute();

   if ($query_pubs) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='';</script>";
   }else{
    echo "Something did not go well ... Try later.";
   }
  }
 }else{
  $n = rand(0, 1000000);
  $img = $n.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $tmp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 

  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload_imagens/".$img);

  $texto = $_POST["texto"];
  $date = date("Y-m-d");
  
  if ($texto == "") {
   echo "You have to write something";
  }else{
   $query_pubs_1 =BD::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO public (`user` , `texto` , `imagem` , `date`) VALUES (:e_1, :t_1, :img, :d_1)");
   $query_pubs_1->bindParam(":e_1", $_SESSION['email_user']);
   $query_pubs_1->bindParam(":t_1", $texto);
   $query_pubs_1->bindParam(":img", $img);
   $query_pubs_1->bindParam(":d_1", $date);
   $query_pubs_1->execute();
   if ($query_pubs_1) {
    //header("Location: ./");
    echo '<script language="javascript">window.location=""</script>';
   }else{
    echo "Something did not go well ... try later. ";
   }
  }
 }

 

}
?>
```

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-date"` é suposto ser `enctype="multipart/form-data"` e confirme que o ficheiro está a ser enviado imprindo o conteudo de `$_FILES` com `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Muito Obrigado!... Acho que era esse o erro que faltava corrigir